# To Date VS To This Day

Tags: meaning

According to dictionaries, "*to date*" seems to be "*to this day*".  So, could "*to date*" be really used in place of "*to this day*" in all contexts?  Or are they subtly different?

Comment: Could _X_ really be used in place of _Y_ “in **all** contexts” smacks of a riddle or a trick question. Did you have an exception in mind already?

Answer (score 5):

They have the same general meaning, *until now*, but they are used in different contexts, and they speak of two very different *now*s.

The present time which is referred to as *this day* is the present era, a vague timespan which may extend for years or decades into the past and future. When we say something like “The anniversary is celebrated to this day” or “That custom continues to this day”, we don’t mean that the anniversary is being celebrated or the custom observed on the day of speaking: we mean that the celebration or observation still takes place whenever it is appropriate.

The present time which is referred to as *date*, however, is the specific day on which the speaker utters the phrase *to date*. This phrase is typically used to report the current status of some activity or expected event:

> We have sold 2,500 units to date, and expect to sell 3,200 by the end of the year.
>   To date he has not responded to my letter.

Note that the verbforms employed with these phrases differ. *To this day* typically modifies a clause cast in the simple present or progressive present, reflecting an action which is repeated or habitual; *to date* typically modifies a clause cast in the present perfect, reflecting a current outcome of prior events.

Comment: And all the dictionaries somehow missed this crucial difference between "*to date*" and "*to this day*".  There should be a reform on dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "to date" only means "to this day" to the extent that "to this day" means "to the present day" or "until and including now", i.e. up to and including that which is returned by /bin/date.

The phrase "to this day" can also be used to refer to some other day indicated.  Imagine, if you will, two people standing at a wall calendar, one saying, "I don't think so. I thought he said he'd be gone to this day, here" and pointing at square indicating a day next month.  In that usage, no, you can't substitute "to date".

Comment: Guess who's been working on a calendaring system in PHP?

Comment: I'm afraid our less tech savvy users might not understand "returned by /bin/date".